# Create Your Own Find String Function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For a school project I have to create a function called find_str that essentially does the same thing as the .find string method, but we cannot use any string methods in our definition.

The project description reads: "Function find_str has two parameters (both strings). It returns the lowest index where the second parameter is found within the first parameter (it returns -1 if the second parameter is not found within the first parameter)."

I have spent a lot of time working on this project and have yet to come to a solution. This is the current definition that I have come up with:

```
def find_str (string, substring):
    index = 0
    length = len (substring)
    for ch in string:
        if ch == substring [0]:
            subindex1 = 0
            subindex2 = index
            for i in range (length):
                if ch == substring [i]:
                    subindex1 +=1
                    if subindex1 == length:
                        return index
                    ch = string [(subindex2)+1]
                    subindex2 +=1
        index += 1
    return "-1"
```

This sample of code only works in some instances, but not all.

For example:

```
print (find_str ("hello", "llo"))
```

returns:

```
2
```

as it should.

But

```
print (find_str ("hello", "el"))
```

returns:

```
   ch = string [(subindex2)+1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I feel like I am overthinking this and there must be is an easier way to do it. Any input or help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Can you be specific about when your function fails - on what input, and how does it fail? Expected output vs. actual, etc.

Comment: For example: print (find_str ("hello", "llo")) returns index 2 which is correct. However, print (find_str ("hello", "el")) returns the error 
"ch = string [(subindex2)+1]
IndexError: string index out of range" when it should return index 1.

Comment: Can you use other python modules like regex? If so you could match the regular expression for the substring in the main string and return it. It's not using any of the python string methods, just a different python module.

Comment: You should edit your question to add the details in your comment. Then you can format the code, etc.

Comment: The instructions say that we cannot use any string methods or import statements in our function definition. I'm very new to python and not familiar with regex. Could you explain more?

Comment: don't forget to catch the obvious case where `string == substring`, and the odd case where `len(substring) > len(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFUsing a sub function to clear your thoughts often help.

```
def find_str (string, substring):
    index = 0
    length = len (substring)
    for j in range(len(string)):
        if is_next_sub(string, substring, j):
            return j        
    return "-1"

def is_next_sub(string, substring, index):
    for i in range(len(substring)):
        if substring[i] != string[index + i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Trying to cram my whole function into one was becoming a bit too complicated. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we should be helping you with 'homework'

How about this:

```
def find_str(string, substring):
    for off in xrange(len(string)):
        if string[off:].startswith(substring):
            return off
    return -1
```

Comment: Not necessarily looking for someone to hand me the answer since it is for school, just hoping someone more experienced could point me in the right direction. I appreciate the response, however, we are not allowed to use the .startswith string method.

Comment: Good response. In any event, if you can't use .startswith, you could _easily_ modify the example to rewrite the slice syntax to specify the length (an exersize for you).

Comment: Could you explain what the .startswith method is actually doing in this example? Again, I am new to python and I'm trying to understand why if I entered: print (find_str("hello", "lo")) - the program would know why the first "l" is not part of the substring. If I can understand the purpose it serves, then I can implement my own solution.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies and time! After messing around with my code for a bit I was able to come up with a solution that worked based on your example. You've saved me a lot of time! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked through your code in detail, but it looks like you're trying to compare characters that don't exist.

Suppose you're searching "aaaaa" for the substring "aaa", and you need to find all matches...

```
String     : aaaaa
Match at 0 : aaa..
Match at 1 : .aaa.
Match at 2 : ..aaa
```

Even though the characters always match, and there five characters in the string, there are only three positions that you might need to consider.

So before you look at the actual characters at all, you can restrict the number of start positions you might need to consider based on the lengths of the string and substring. You only loop for those start positions. That means you're not looping for start positions that cannot match. Also, if you *don't* do this...

```
String     : aaaaa
Match at 0 : aaa..
Match at 1 : .aaa.
Match at 2 : ..aaa
Match at 3 : ...aa!
Match at 4 : ....a!!
```

Those exclamation points are places where you try to match a character in the substring with a character that doesn't exist, after the end of the string. You can check for that within the loop to avoid the error each time it occurs, but why not eliminate all those cases at once by not looping for the match positions that cannot occur?

The number of start positions you may need to check is `len(fullstring) + 1 - len(substring)`, so you can derive a range of possible start positions using `range(0, len(fullstring) + 1 - len(substring))`.